# open iOS app from another app

Tags: ios, launching-application, openurl

I am trying to open my app `MyApp` from another app, I've already defined the custom url for `MyApp` (i.e. `myapp://`).

If I write `myapp://` in safari and click on go it will open `MyApp`. Now what I want is a simple app with only a `UIButton` **"Launch MyApp"** and when I click it `MyApp` will launch.

I tried it by doing this:

```
-(IBAction)launchMyApp:(id)sender
{
    NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myapp://"];
    NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
}
```

but nothing happened. If it is possible to implement this functionality please provide me the code.

Thanks

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"URL: %@", myurl);` print?

Comment: In general, `myapp://something` will be better than just `myapp://`

Comment: That should work, have you checked that the button is linked in interface builder?

Comment: @PhillipMills: it simply prints `testApp[5019:11303] myapp://`

Comment: @jjv360: button is properly linked in IB, but when I click on button `MyApp` won't launch.

Comment: Did you check using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL]

Comment: @Sulthan: I don't understand why the `MyApp` is launching when I type `my app://` in safari. but not launching from my second app.

Comment: @AnkurArya They can handle URIs differently. Safari is part of the system so it doesn't have to use the same API you are using.

Comment: @Sulthan: can you please tell me how can I handle URI in my case ?

Comment: Have you verified, using the debugger, that your `launchMyApp:` method is actually being called? Are you testing this on a real device or the simulator? Test on a real device to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved the problem**

I don't know how but it worked with the same code I've written in the question:

```
-(IBAction)launchMyApp:(id)sender
{
    NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myapp://"];
    NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works in Safari, it may work in a `UIWebView`. Try displaying the page you used in Safari in a `UIWebView` and see if it wokrs !

Answer (score 0):

Use some actual URI, not just scheme and then nothing, e.g. `myapp://launch`.